# Why OnClick method isn't executing?

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have problem with my OnClick method. I don't know why it isn't executing. `OnClickListener` is set on button (`R.id.signOutButton`) in `fragment_user` layout. When I click on it nothing is happening.

```
public class UserFragment extends Fragment {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    public Button signOutBtn;
    private static final String TAG = "UserFragment";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);
        signOutBtn = RootView.findViewById(R.id.signOutButton);
        Log.d(TAG, "OnCreateRun");
        signOutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "OnClickRun");
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Welcome!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
                openSingUpActivity();
                signOut();
            }
        });
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);
    }

    private void openBottomNavigationBarActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), BottomNavigationBar.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void openSingUpActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SignUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        if (user != null) {
            openBottomNavigationBarActivity();
        }
    }
}
```

I used a log messages and `Log.d(TAG, "OnCreateRun");` is visible but `Log.d(TAG, "OnClickRun");` isn't.
Please help, thanks.

Comment: did you actually click the button? have you debugged your code?

Comment: Yes, I clicked on button and debugged code.

Comment: Did your code actually go into that onClick? if not, either you may be checking a wrong listener, or you might be checking/clocking a wrong Button

Comment: Perhaps you should return `RootView`, instead of discarding it and calling `inflater.inflate()` again, which creates a new copy of the view that doesn't have an OnClickListener registered.

Comment: You are awesome, thanks a lot :)